# How do I preserve HTML from the XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create myself a news page using PHP. However, I ran into a little bit of a roadblock. I want each post to be separated, to only have 5 posts at a time loaded, *and* for the HTML to be preserved. I got the first two, but the third is becoming a problem.

I've tried everything I can. I don't exactly know how each function is interacting with each other, so I always break something when trying to add something new. I tried using saveHTML() in here, but no matter where I place it, it either does nothing or breaks something.

All I want is for the post's content to preserve the HTML, some posts have unordered lists, and some have links.

By the way, here is the code:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://screenbones.com/news.xml');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

        echo '<article>';
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo $description;
        echo '</article>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `'desc' => $rss->saveHTML($node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)),`

Comment: @Musa This is what happens: Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in .../feedTest.php on line 34

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: @Musa Version 5.2 PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the `nodeValue` property of `<description>` which is just the text content. Use the [DOMDocument::saveHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) method with the node instead.

<sub><sub>Edit: Credit goes to [Musa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa). My original answer was wrong. The <article> tags made me think OP was producing XML for some reason..</sub></sub>

Comment: If I replace nodeValue with saveHTML, the post content doesn't show up, but with saveHTML(), I get this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveHTML() in ../feedTest.php on line 34.

This is what I'm trying: 
`'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->saveHTML()`

Comment: `saveHTML()` is a method of `DOMDocument`, not `DOMElement`. Try doing this instead: `'desc' => $rss->saveHTML($node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)),`

Comment: The problem with that code is you're giving parameters to saveHTML, which creates errors when running it.

Comment: `saveHTML($node)` is supported since PHP 5.3.6. You might get away with using `saveXML($node)` instead (if you are on an older PHP version).

Answer (score 0):

Typically RSS feed use CDATA section/text field in description element with serialized XML. In your case XHTML is used, but without defining the namespace.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('http://screenbones.com/news.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item[position() <= 5]') as $item) {
  $title = $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item);
  $link = $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $item);
  $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($xpath->evaluate('string(date)', $item)));

  if ($xpath->evaluate('count(description/*) > 0', $item)) {
    $descriptionFragment = '';
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('description/node()', $item) as $content) {
      $descriptionFragment .= $document->saveHtml($content);
    }
  } else {
    $descriptionFragment = $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $item);
  }

  printf (
    '<article>
       <p><strong><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a></strong><br />
       <small><em>Posted on %2$s</em></small></p>
       %3$s
     </article>',
    htmlspecialchars($link),
    htmlspecialchars($title),
    htmlspecialchars($date),
    $descriptionFragment 
  );
}
```

The example uses Xpath expressions, which allow you to fetch nodes and values from you DOM.

The first expression `//item[position() <= 5]` fetches the first five `item` elements. For the other expression the `$item` node is used as context, so they are relative to it.

Expression like `string(title)` fetch the element nodes by name and cast the first found node into a string. If no node is found, it returns an empty string.

`count(description/*) > 0` checks if here are element nodes inside the description (not only text/cdata nodes). If this is the case it iterates all child nodes in the description and serializes them to HTML. Otherwise it read the single text node as serialized HTML.

`htmlspecialchars()` is used to escape characters like `&` for HTML output. Be careful with the `$descriptionFragment`. It is HTML directly from the external source. You might want to cleanup that before using it.

Comment: With saveHTML, PHP is complaining that there are parameters being given, it wants 0.

Comment: That means you have an really old (insecure) PHP version. However you could copy all the nodes into a separate document save it.

Comment: I realize it's an old version. I don't see any option through my web host to update it.